# How to print labels with an auto increasing hexadecimal serial number? (vb.net)

Tags: vb.net, printing

How can I print for example 1000 labels and each one have it's own unique serial number, using an auto increment method?

Printer is an Avery AP 4.4

Comment: Have you heard of a mail merge?

Comment: I just took a look of what it is. If i understood, this software will create a document for each serial number and send them one by one to the printer as seperate jobs. Is this a good practice?

Comment: People do this all the time. Just use excel to generate your 1000 serial numbers, layout your label in Word, and then do a mail merge to the Excel spreadsheet. If this is something you'll need to repeat often, you may want to program it... but for one run, or for infrequent runs, this will be easier.

Comment: thank you for your help. However, I did it programmaticaly cause I had to implement this in an application written in vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Solutions:

**Solution 1**

1. Have a class variable to store the serial number.
2. Create a print document.
3. Draw the string(serial number variable) in the print document's
   printpage.
4. Call the print method which will print this printdocument, from
   inside a for loop (that runs for as many times as you wish to
   increment the serial and print it)
5. 5.Increase the serial number by 1

The rest will be done by the print method that fires the printpage event of the printdocument where a new serial number will be drawn each time cause the serial number variable will be increased by 1.

This creates multiple printer jobs but until now, it seems there is no problem with that.

**Solution 2 (Using EPL2 Printers Language)**

1. Create your EPL2 Code using an array like this:

   ```
      Dim RawData_array(7) As String
   RawData_array(0) = "450"
   RawData_array(1) = "#!A1"
   RawData_array(2) = "#IMS38/12.0/"
   RawData_array(3) = "#ERN"
   RawData_array(4) = "#R-3.6/-2.4"
   RawData_array(5) = "#J6#T6#YT108/0///"
   RawData_array(6) = "#J6#T24.5#YT108/0///"
   RawData_array(7) = "#Q1/"
   ```
2. Create a For loop
3. Inside the loop append the serial number (as a string) to the end of element 5 and element 6
4. Build a string with all arrays elements using a stringbuilder like this:

   `For i As Integer = 0 To RawData_array.Length - 1
   sb.AppendLine(RawData_array(i))
   Next`
5. Send the string to the printer like this:
   `RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter("Your_Printers_Name", sb.ToString)`

**THIS SECOND SOLUTION IS THE ONE I FINALLY USED CAUSE ITS MORE LIGHTWEIGHT FOR SOME REASON**

I hope it helps someone sometime!..

PS. This EPL2 settings are for 16x8mm labels that come as two in every label's roll row.